# BibLaTeX - How to remove the period after p/pp in Bibliography only

Tags: biblatex

For my Thesis I almost entirely adjusted the authoryear biblatex style, however one last thing remains: In the Bibliography only I need to replace the

'p.' and 'pp.' with

'p' and 'pp'. How would I accomplish that?

I know that `\mkpageprefix` is being used to generate these characters, but the biblatex manual seems not to account for someone who wants to adapt this behavior.

Does anyone have a clue?

All the best,
David

Answer (score 10):

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  page             = {p\ifbibliography{}{\adddot}},
  pages            = {pp\ifbibliography{}{\adddot}},
}
```

should be enough. We just check if we are in the bibliography, if not we get to see the dot.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  page             = {p\ifbibliography{}{\adddot}},
  pages            = {pp\ifbibliography{}{\adddot}},
} 

\begin{document}
\cite[1]{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]